# React native map crashes when deploy app to Testflight (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight

I have a page in my app that is supposed to show a map and track the location of the user displaying a blue line behind the person. when I try out the app on expo it works perfectly but after Uploading it to testflight and testing, when I open this page, the app crashes. here is my code. maybe one can point out to the issue would be great.

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
  PermissionsAndroid
} from "react-native";
import MapView, {
  Marker,
  AnimatedRegion,
  Polyline,
  PROVIDER_GOOGLE
} from "react-native-maps";
import haversine from "haversine";
import { func } from "prop-types";
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {db} from '../App';


// const LATITUDE = 29.95539;
// const LONGITUDE = 78.07513;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.009;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.009;
const LATITUDE = 37.78825;
const LONGITUDE = -122.4324;

import * as Location from 'expo-location';


class AnimatedMarkers extends React.Component {
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: LATITUDE,
      longitude: LONGITUDE,
      routeCoordinates: [],
      distanceTravelled: 0,
      prevLatLng: {},
      useNativeDriver: true,
      coordinate: new AnimatedRegion({
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0,
        useNativeDriver: true
      })
    };
  }

  // new
  async getLocationAsync() {
    // permissions returns only for location permissions on iOS and under certain conditions, see Permissions.LOCATION
    const { status, permissions } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status === 'granted') {
      return Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
    } else {
      throw new Error('Location permission not granted');
    }
  }
  // new

  componentDidMount() {
    const { coordinate } = this.state;

    // new
    this.getLocationAsync(); 
    // new
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      position => {
        const { routeCoordinates, distanceTravelled } = this.state;
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

        const newCoordinate = {
          latitude,
          longitude
        };

        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
          if (this.marker) {
            this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
              newCoordinate,
              500
            );
          }
        } else {
          coordinate.timing(newCoordinate).start();
        }

        // aqui upload to Firebase
        const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var date = new Date().getDate();
        var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
        var year = new Date().getFullYear();
        let fullDate = date + '-' + month + '-' + year;
        db.ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/'+fullDate).push().set({latitude: latitude,longitude: longitude,})
            .then(() => console.log('Data set.'));

        this.setState({
          latitude,
          longitude,
          routeCoordinates: routeCoordinates.concat([newCoordinate]),
          distanceTravelled:
            distanceTravelled + this.calcDistance(newCoordinate),
          prevLatLng: newCoordinate
        });
      },
      error => console.log(error),
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000,
        distanceFilter: 10
      }
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
  }

  getMapRegion = () => ({
    latitude: this.state.latitude,
    longitude: this.state.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
  });

  calcDistance = newLatLng => {
    const { prevLatLng } = this.state;
    return haversine(prevLatLng, newLatLng) || 0;
  };

  handleViaje = () => {
    var date = new Date().getDate();
    var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    let fullDate = date + '-' + month + '-' + year;
    const { distanceTravelled } = this.state;
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var data = {
        isActive: "false"
    }
    let nuevaDistancia = distanceTravelled;
    db.ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/distancias/'+fullDate).on('value', (snapshot) => {
        const userObj = snapshot.val();
        console.log('puto');
        nuevaDistancia = nuevaDistancia + userObj.distancia;
    })
    db.ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/distancias/'+fullDate+'/').update({distancia: nuevaDistancia})
    db.ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/isActive').update(data)

    // getting the time
    let d = new Date();
    let hours = d.getHours();
    let minutes = d.getMinutes();
    let seconds = d.getSeconds() + minutes*60 + hours*60*60;
    
    let totalSeconds = 0;

    db.ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/tripTempInformation').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        const userObj = snapshot.val();
        let prevSecond = userObj.seconds;
        totalSeconds = seconds - prevSecond;
    });
    db.ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/tiempos/'+fullDate+'/').push({seconds: totalSeconds});
    //update

    let seconValues = 0;
    db.ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/tiempos/'+fullDate+'/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        const userObj = snapshot.val();
        for(let obj in userObj){
            db.ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/tiempos/'+fullDate+'/'+obj).on('value', (snapshot) => {
                if(snapshot.val().seconds){
                    seconValues = seconValues + snapshot.val().seconds;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    db.ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/tiempos/'+fullDate+'/').update({seconds: seconValues});
    // end here


    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          showUserLocation
          followUserLocation
          loadingEnabled
          region={this.getMapRegion()}
        >
          <Polyline coordinates={this.state.routeCoordinates} strokeWidth={5} />
          <Marker.Animated
            ref={marker => {
              this.marker = marker;
            }}
            coordinate={this.state.coordinate}
          />
        </MapView>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.bubble, styles.button]}>
            <Text style={styles.bottomBarContent}>
              {parseFloat(this.state.distanceTravelled).toFixed(2)} km
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button2} onPress={this.handleViaje}>
                    <Text style={{color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500"}}>Terminar Viaje</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  },
  bubble: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.7)",
    paddingHorizontal: 18,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    borderRadius: 20
  },
  latlng: {
    width: 200,
    alignItems: "stretch"
  },
  button: {
    width: 80,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 10
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginVertical: 20,
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },
  button2: {
    marginHorizontal: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#E9446A",
    borderRadius: 4,
    height: 52,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
},
});

export default AnimatedMarkers;
```

Comment: Are you able to see any crashlogs? There should be for sure some.. if not try to build .ipa as an ad-hoc and install it directly on your iPhone, might be worth to check that way.

Comment: No crash logs, I have tried everything. Will try the ad-hoc now